# Rename/add prefix to third party app template tags?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-apps, django-template-filters, templatetags

Is it possible to add prefix or rename third party app template tags?

Explanation:

We use `django_tables2` in our project. For performance purposes, we decided to migrate from `django_tables2` to `django_datatable` (https://github.com/shymonk/django-datatable).

We want to use `django_tables2` for a couple of tables and migrate rest of them to `django_datatable`.

The problem is that both `django_tables2` and `django_datatable` uses the same template tag `{% render_table table %}`. And maybe there will be more problems when we go deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reregister the tag with a different name:

```
from table.templatetags.table_tags import register, render_table

register.tag('datatable_render_table', render_table)
```

You should put this somewhere it is executed during startup, for example in `AppConfig.ready()`.

Comment: This is a very nice solution. Just to add, its necessary to load datatable tags before django_tables tags because render_table tag is not unregistered.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the simplest way would be to just split the code in multiple templates (possibly, includes), so you won't have both `{% load django_tables %}` and `{% load table_tags %}` (from django-datatable) in the same file. This won't require anything fancy, and would work with any Django version.

As for renaming, I don't think there is a readily available way built in. There is a syntax to import only specific tags/filters (`{% load render_table from table_tags %}`) but no way to rename them.

One way is to implement custom loader. You should probably take a look at [`django.template.defaulttags.load`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1070) source code, and copy that, implementing your own `load_ex` with a custom `{% load_ex render_table as render_table_dt from table_tags %}` syntax. Basically, all you have to do is to add extended syntax parsing and rename `lib.tags` keys (it's just a dict, mapping from a tag name to a function) according to the rules provided.

Or - a dirtier approach - hook into [`django.template.defaulttags.find_library`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/template/defaulttags.py#L1036). There, you have both the library `name` and `parser` instance, so something like this:

```
# Somewhere in your project's init code...
if not hasattr(defaulttags.find_library, "_is_hacked"):
    real_find_library = defaulttags.find_library
    def find_library(parser, name):
        lib = real_find_library(parser, name)
        if name == "django_tables2" and "render_table" in lib.tags:
            lib.tags["render_table2"] = lib.tags["render_table"]
            del lib.tags["render_table"]
        return lib
    find_library._is_hacked = True
    defaulttags.find_library = find_library
```

This should be sufficient to rename the tag. I haven't tested the code at all (sorry if there are any typos or some mistakes), but you should get the idea.